# Insert alternative roads into OpeenStreetMap from a shapefile file. It's possible?

Tags: r, openstreetmap, shapefile, r-sf, osrm

I would like to ask a question:  I used the code below to find the shortest path between one point and another, using a point file that is in the shapefile format. I was able to insert the route and plot on the map using the osrm package. The route is plotted and is viewed by OpenStreetMap, as you can see in the attachment.
However, I have another shapefile file that is just highways and has alternative roads that OpeenStreetMap does not have.

So, is it possible to insert these alternative roads in some way in OpenStreetMap? If not, you could indicate alternatives for what I can do, as I want to plot this shortest path on the map, however the OP does not have all possible roads.

```
library(sf)
library(osrm)
library(cartography)

shp<-read_sf("point_UTM.shp")
shp<-st_transform(shp,4326) #

#shortest path between 9 and 15
dr<-osrmRoute(shp[9,],shp[15,], returnclass = "sf")
plot(st_geometry(dr))

#create route for map
route <- osrmRoute(src = shp[9,], dst = shp[15,],
                   overview = "full", returnclass = "sf")

#Map view
osm <- getTiles(x = route, crop = TRUE, type = "osm", zoom = 13)
tilesLayer(osm)

# add map route
tilesLayer(osm)
plot(st_geometry(route), lwd = 4, add = TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(route), lwd = 1, col = "white", add = TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(shp[c(9,15),]), pch = 20, col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Alternative routes? Are you asking about roads instead?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes  Friend. Could you  help me?

Comment: Unfortunately no, never worked with shapefiles so far. For merging OSM files (XML or PBF) see osmium-tool.

Comment: @Jose you can use the SpatialLines function from the sf package and then addPolylines from the Leaflet package.